# Avoid new lines in csv because of carriage return with php

Tags: php, csv

doing my few first steps in PHP and I'm stuck. Been searching SO all afternoon but couldn't come up with a solution. Highly appreciate any advice from experienced devs.

**Scenario:**
Users are asked to fill out a short survey consisting of two textareas. Upon hitting the submit button, the content of the textareas is written to a csv file.

**Problem:**
My problem is that (while it does write the content) whenever people use carriage return in the textarea, it results in a new line in the csv file, thus messing it up. I've spent the afternoon reading up on stackoverflow and trying to use str_replace(); for rewriting all \n with spaces " ", alas to no avail.

Here is my **HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<title>Survey name here</title>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
</head>

<body>
<?php
if(!empty($errorMessage)) 
{
echo("<p>Error!</p>\n");
echo("<ul>" . $errorMessage . "</ul>\n");
} 
?>

<div id="content">
<h1>Survey</h1>

<form action="post.php" method="post" id="survey">

<p><strong>Question 1:</strong><br />Do you like it or not?</p>
<p><textarea rows="6" cols="100" name="question1" value="<?=$answer;?>"><?php echo $answer ?></textarea></p>

<p><strong>Question 2:</strong><br />Would you prefer this or that?</p>
<p><textarea rows="6" cols="100" name="question2" value="<?=$answer2;?>"><?php echo $answer2 ?></textarea></p>

<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" id="submit" onclick="return Validate()"/>
</form>
</div><!-- End Content -->

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the **PHP** part:

```
<?php
if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")
{
$answer1 = $_POST['question1'];
$answer2 = $_POST['question2'];

// report error when not answered
$errorMessage = "";
if(empty($_POST['question1']))
{
$errorMessage .= "<li class='errormsg'>Please answer the question No. 1!</li>";
}
if(empty($_POST['question2']))
{
$errorMessage .= "<li class='errormsg'>Please answer the question No. 2!</li>";
}

// sending to CSV
if(empty($errorMessage)) 
{
str_replace('\r\n', ' ', $answer1 . $answer2);
$fs = fopen("test.csv","a");
fwrite($fs,$answer1 . ";" . $answer2 . "\n");
fclose($fs);

// after submit, head to thank you page 
header("Location: thankyou.php");
exit;
}
}
?>
```

I figure I'm not applying the str_replace() function correctly. Who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [fputcsv](https://www.php.net/fputcsv) instead of fwrite.

```
if(empty($errorMessage)) 
{
    $fs = fopen("test.csv","a");
    fputcsv($fs, Array($answer1, $answer2), ';');
    fclose($fs);

    // after submit, head to thank you page 
    header("Location: thankyou.php");
    exit;
}
```

As a side note, `"\r\n"` and `'\r\n'` are not the same thing in PHP.  The first one is "carriage return, new line", the second is litterally "backslash-r, backslash-n"

Comment: I was not aware of the difference between "" and '' - thanks Matt!

Comment: @SebastianP glad to be of help. Please upvote me or accept my answer if it helped you!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
  $string = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $string);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Vlad, that helped me to get it to work by changing my str_replace() line into $answer1 = str_replace("\r\n", " ", $answer1);